# Displaying parsed HTML output using Velocity

Tags: velocity

i have a velocity template...

It contains the following tag:

```
#field('itemname')
```

The "itemname" variable contains this:

```
<i>Some</i> <b>Example Title</b>
```

The source of the outputted page has this:

> <i>Some</i>
>   <b>Example Title</b>

So, the user sees the actual HTML tags:

```
<i>Some</i> <b>Example Title</b>
```

What I want them to see is:

*Some* **Example Title**

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What does #field do? Do you have same behavior with html inside any other variable?

Comment: Alex, can you please let us know how you fixed your problem?  The answer that you accepted doesn't seem to help. Thanks!

Comment: This was over 3 years ago, and I don't have access to the original code, sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I see right from your snippets, the problem is not with the velocity template, but with the mime type encoding of the HTTP Response your user is receiving. It should be "text/html", but I suspect it's something else, and so, the browser is showing the tags instead  of "rendering" them to what they represent.

Of course, I don't know what your

```
#field()
```

macro does, so the problem might be something else, e.g. that macro might generate a wrapping PRE tag or a Text Area, and this might be the cause you why the those B and I tags are displayed as they are instead of being rendered.